# JSON Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists

Tags: mysql, json

This is continuation of [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists), but this time i want to update the json entry in mysql

Below is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TAG_COUNTER (
    account       varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    time_id       INT NOT NULL,
    counters      JSON,
    PRIMARY KEY   (account, time_id)
)
```

example data's are like below.

```
'google', '20180510', '{"gmail_page_viewed" : 12000300, "search_page_viewed" : 9898884726423}'
```

Actually i always want to update (increment the counter ) of this table. but every day start time_id(yyyyMMdd) is new hence counter json dont have the counter key (e.g.`gmail_page_viewed`).

So the solution i want is create new json key  column with 
`value = 1` when it is not exists. e.g. `{"gmail_page_viewed" : 1}`

if counter (e.g. `gmail_page_viewed`) key exists then increment the 
`value = value + 1`

So help me on a insert query with update if json counter exists.

> UPDATE_1 (INFO: Always use IFNULL when working with json)

I have used the solution suggested by @wchiquito but seeing the below issue.

Very first time (after schema creation); tried the below sql

```
  INSERT INTO `TAG_COUNTER`
  (`partner_id`, `time_id`, `counters`)
VALUES
  ('google', '20180510', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `counters` =
  JSON_SET(`counters`,
           '$.gmail_page_viewed',
           JSON_EXTRACT(`counters`,
                        '$.gmail_page_viewed') + 1
  );
```

and got the below response; which is correct as expected.

```
'google', '20180510', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1}'
```

Then tried with different counter in the next query,

```
  INSERT INTO `TAG_COUNTER`
  (`account`, `time_id`, `counters`)
VALUES
  ('google', '20180510', '{"search_page_viewed": 1}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `counters` =
  JSON_SET(`counters`,
           '$.search_page_viewed',
           JSON_EXTRACT(`counters`,
                        '$.search_page_viewed') + 1
  );
```

and got the below.

```
'google', '20180510', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": null}'
```

**Any idea why this new counter search_page_viewed is set with NULL ..?**

> UPDATE_2 (INFO: Use double quote around key when number is used as key)

I have faced below issue as well, and solved the it from that answer

[Mysql 5.7 ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958183/mysql-5-7-error-3143-42000-invalid-json-path-expression-the-error-is-around)

> UPDATE_3 (Info: Group by, ensure WHERE with "NOT NULL" or "> 0"

Getting the count per time frame (e.g. by day, month, year)

```
  SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(time_id, 1, 6) AS month, 
  SUM(counters->>'$.gmail_page_viewed') 
  FROM TAG_COUNTER 
  WHERE counters->>'$.gmail_page_viewed' > 0
  GROUP BY month;
```

> UPDATE_4 (Question: )

I would like see the trending page per time (hour/day/month/year)
From the below query i can get the count per time but only if i know the key (gmail_page_viewed).

```
  SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(time_id, 1, 6) AS month, 
  SUM(counters->>'$.gmail_page_viewed') 
  FROM TAG_COUNTER 
  WHERE counters->>'$.gmail_page_viewed' > 0
  GROUP BY month;
```

But what i want is how do i know the overall trending of the page count per time? So I need something like below, Please help.

```
group by SUBSTRING(time_id, 1, 6) AS month, KEY
order by SUM(counters->>'$.KEY')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your requirement, however, the following script can give you some ideas, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f7cfe549dcfdf77e2dc4d915213b4aa).

Comment: @wchiquito That is awesome! One question you have updated the `gmail_page_viewed` but not updated the `search_page_viewed`? How to update both in this case ?

Comment: See updated [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4246d5b1f3397cb2914062fd63929060).

Comment: @wchiquito Excellent! That is what i want. Thank you! very much. Could you please add this as answer below, so that i can accept it?

Comment: See updated [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47c527f140cd7a519b43cd63b09dd49f).

Comment: `... SUM(IFNULL(counters->>'$."gmail_page_viewed"', 0)) ...` and `... IFNULL(counters->>'$."gmail_page_viewed"', 0) > 0 ...`.

Comment: @wchiquito you have helped me a lot, last one question, how to get trending page (which has more count) for day/month/year. The problem is in group by i have to know the key to get the count, but is it possible to get the trending without knowing key. Let me update the question.

Comment: Maybe you need a dynamic query, see [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: @wchiquito This is similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650221/mysql-sum-json-values-grouped-by-json-keys and i think i have to go from `{"key1" : "value1", "key2":"value2" }` to `[{"name" : "key1", "value":"value1" }, {"name" : "key2", "value":"value2" }, ...]`, so that i can add `name` into my `group by` along with time ??

Comment: @wchiquito asked update_4 as a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297616/mysql-json-based-trending-tags-implementation with bounty..? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script can be useful for your requirement:

```sql
INSERT INTO `TAG_COUNTER`
  (`account`, `time_id`, `counters`)
VALUES
  ('google', '20180510', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 50}'),
  ('google', '20180510', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 50}'),
  ('google', '20180511', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 100}'),
  ('google', '20180511', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 100}'),
  ('google', '20180511', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 100}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `counters` =
  JSON_SET(`counters`,
           '$."gmail_page_viewed"',
           IFNULL(`counters` ->> '$."gmail_page_viewed"', 0) + 1,
           '$."search_page_viewed"',
           IFNULL(`counters` ->> '$."search_page_viewed"', 0) + 1
  );
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4dbd8cdd00d31410e61ac5fa6f6fc93a).

Comment: I see different problem when following the solutions. Could you please help on the update ..?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: Remember to adjust the script according to your needs, see updated [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47c527f140cd7a519b43cd63b09dd49f).