# MySql Inner JSON Insert or update if exists

Tags: mysql, json

As per this [JSON Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271455/json-insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists), I got answer mysql to insert/update the below json.

```
"google", 
"20180510", 
"{
   "gmail_page_viewed" : 12000300, 
   "search_page_viewed" : 9898884726423
 }"
```

into the SCHEMA

```
CREATE TABLE TAG_COUNTER (
    account       varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    time_id       INT NOT NULL,
    counters      JSON,
    PRIMARY KEY   (account, time_id)
)
```

like below

```
INSERT INTO `TAG_COUNTER`
  (`account`, `time_id`, `counters`)
VALUES
  ('google', '20180510', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 1}'),
  ('google', '20180510', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 1}'),
  ('google', '20180511', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 1}'),
  ('google', '20180511', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 1}'),
  ('google', '20180512', '{"gmail_page_viewed": 1, "search_page_viewed": 1}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `counters` =
  JSON_SET(`counters`,
           '$."gmail_page_viewed"',
           IFNULL(`counters` ->> '$."gmail_page_viewed"', 0) + 1,
           '$."search_page_viewed"',
           IFNULL(`counters` ->> '$."search_page_viewed"', 0) + 1
  );
```

However it is difficult to retrieve the data from it using group by, since json key is dynamic and not static.

So if i change my json to have static keys (e.g. page_name, page_visits) to the below format, to make retrieval (groupby/orderby) is easy.

```
"google", 
"20180510", 
'{
   "gmail_page_viewed" : {"page_name" : "gmail_page_viewed", "page_visits" : 12000300}, 
   "search_page_viewed" : {"page_name" : "search_page_viewed", "page_visits" : 12000300}
 }"
```

But i couldn't figure out how to prepare `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query. I have tried for more than 6 hours, but no luck, either data is not inserted properly, or not updating the visit count properly. sometime quote gets added into the content.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ` requires a UNIQUE key on your table do you have one?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes I have updated the schema into the question.

Comment: I don't understand the whole problem, but the following query can give you some ideas, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2c96eecc3b0ded293f944503b11f9dc).

Comment: @wchiquito Thanks, i will test confirm you. One thing I see the update only involves page visits, so when new tag come after already record/tag will not update name i guess, but will update you after testing.

Comment: @wchiquito Thank you!! and your solution nearly same what i have asked. But when the account and time_id is same and when trying to insert new different tag, it is not updating properly. This is because of already a row is created for that primary key and next row insert/update is failing. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7674491325798342fe371c827566a824

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3febf68298318a1ea54b78998d549073).

Comment: @wchiquito As usual it looks what i needed. Thank you!! One doubt how `"page_name": "g_page_viewed"` got added, since it is not part of `JSON_SET`? there is only mention about the `page_visits` after/under `JSON_SET` section.